# передать текст с помощью JSON

Tags: javascript, php, json

Такой форсмажорный случай. Вытаскиваю пост из mySQL через php конвертирую пост в JSON и открываю в html документе все работает, все ок. Но. из текста исчезли пробелы. Кодировка utf-8 в базе пост было UTF-8 general_si. Перерыл весь нет, даже не приходит в голову как правильно составить поиск. JSON съедает пробелы и хочестя найти способ их вставить. или найти метод вытаскивать посты из базы данных через джейсон. Ставил пробелы через .join(' '); их все равно почему то не видно.
полный сайт тут https://nasobe.ru/team/index.html
Заранее большое спасибо за любую помощь! Отличного времени суток и волшебного настроения!

```
<script>
function readTextFile(file, callback) {
let rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
callback(rawFile.responseText);
}
}
rawFile.send(null);
}
//usage:
readTextFile("site/team.json", function(text){
let data = JSON.parse(text);
console.log(Object.values(data));
// document.getElementById('json').innerHTML=Object.values(data[0][2]).join(' ');
document.getElementById('h1').innerHTML=Object.values(data[2][1]).join(" ");
document.getElementById('four').innerHTML=Object.values(data[2][4]).join(' ');
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=Object.values(data[2][6]).join(' ');
document.getElementById('description').innerHTML=Object.values(data[2][2]).join(' ');
document.getElementById('ancor').innerHTML=Object.values(data[2][3]).join(' ');

});
</script>
```

PHP------------------------------

```
if(isset($_POST['connect'])){
$connect=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);
if($connect==false){
printf("Ошибка: Невозможно полключиться к SQL ". mysqli_connect_error());
}else{
printf('ok');
}
mysqli_query($connect, "SET NAMES utf8");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `team`";
$textPost=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM `team` ORDER BY `id`, `title`,`description`,`text`  ASC");
$ArrayTextPost=mysqli_fetch_all($textPost);
$obj = new ArrayObject($ArrayTextPost);
file_get_contents($obj);
file_put_contents('team.json',json_encode($obj));
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($obj);
// var_dump($textPost);
echo '</pre>';
header('location: /team/get-post-php.html');
}else if(isset($_POST['JSON'])){
$connect=mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);
if($connect==false){
printf("Ошибка: Невозможно полключиться к SQL ". mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: Покажите как php файл отдаёт.

Comment: Дааааааа.... *Такого* я ещё не видел.

Comment: )) жестяк, массив кидает в объект, а потом пытается считать содержимое файла из объекта, опосля редирект - из всего этого рукоблудия js должен считать json

Comment: все смешалось в доме облонских

Comment: так тут же есть способ для передачи: let data = JSON.parse(text); И массив отлично становится объектом, успешно передаётся. Но вопрос тут совершенно в другом. Почему в тексте исчезли пробелы?

Answer (score -2):

Вопрос решон. Все было в том что к объекту с помощью .join('  '); установлено два пробела, а установка их по уполномочию привязалась к каждому символу в объекте и пробелы ставились между каждым символом. + один пробел между слов. Пустой .join(''); тоесть без бробелов разделения решает этоу несуразицу.